# building a matrix with specific values using for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I would like to build a matrix with specific values using for loop in R.

- Column names: `unique(flowdata$name)`
- Row names: `unique(flowdata$attrs[which(flowdata$metadata=='name')])`
- Values: the *meanValue* of the *outputGroup* 0 and 2.*

Below is my code but when i run it, I get an error saying

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, row.name, col.name, value = 6876) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

The matrix I want to create: for the first column "Acetic acid, at plant", it should return value of "1" for "Acetic acid, at plant (in row 1)", and "0.18841" for "Recovered energy, at acetic acid production (at row 2)".

Here is my shortened sample data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/10it07wqzfwctd6/Data_Sample.txt?dl=0

```
n.up = length(unique(flowdata$name)) # number of unit processes
n.p = length(unique(flowdata$attrs[which(flowdata$metadata=='name')]))
  #number of inputs/outputs

output.mat <- matrix(0,n.p,n.up) #empty matrix

colnames(output.mat) <- unique(flowdata$name) # up names
rownames(output.mat) <- 
    unique(flowdata$attrs[which(flowdata$metadata=='name')]) 
    # inputs/outputs names

# check output.mat size

data <- flowdata
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){ # for every row in data

if ((data$metadata[i]=='outputGroup' && data$attrs[i] == 0) || 
  (data$metadata[i]=='outputGroup' && data$attrs[i] == 2)){ # if it is an 
 #output and it is a reference product or a co-product

 col.name <- data$name[i] # up name
 row.name <- data$attrs[i-4] # i/o name

 value <- as.numeric(data$attrs[i-5]) #value

 output.mat[row.name,col.name] <- value
}
 }

output.mat <- output.mat[-which(rowSums(output.mat)==0),] # if the row is 
   #empty, then the flow was an input or output of no interest
```

Comment: You will probably get faster help if you post a *small* reproducible data sample in your question. Is it really so complex that you need to ask people to download thousands of rows of data to illustrate the problem? Most problems can be illlustrated with less than 20 lines of data.

Comment: You will find that you get higher quality help and faster help on the site if you (1) provide *small, copy/paste-able* sample data, (2) describe what you are doing in words as well as code, and (3) show the desired output for your sample input. The text of your question describes your data but does not describe at all what your code is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

output.mat returns values <> 0.  Your code will not run as you provided; however.  In some place you say your data is stored in 'flowdata' while in other places in 'data'.  Below is a quick fix with the out.

```
n.up = length(unique(flowdata$name)) # number of unit processes
n.p = length(unique(flowdata$attrs[which(flowdata$metadata=='name')]))
#number of inputs/outputs

output.mat <- matrix(0,n.p,n.up) #empty matrix

colnames(output.mat) <- unique(flowdata$name) # up names
rownames(output.mat) <- 
unique(flowdata$attrs[which(flowdata$metadata=='name')]) 
# inputs/outputs names

# check output.mat size

data <- flowdata
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){ # for every row in data

  if ((data$metadata[i]=='outputGroup' && data$attrs[i] == 0) || 
      (data$metadata[i]=='outputGroup' && data$attrs[i] == 2)){ # if it is an 
    #output and it is a reference product or a co-product

col.name <- data$name[i] # up name
row.name <- data$attrs[i-4] # i/o name

value <- as.numeric(data$attrs[i-5]) #value

output.mat[row.name,col.name] <- value
  }
}

output.mat <- output.mat[-which(rowSums(output.mat)==0),] # if the row is empty, then the flow was an input or output of no interest

print(output.mat)
```

Output looks like:

```
                                            Acetic acid, at plant
Acetic acid, at plant                                     1.00000
Recovered energy, at acetic acid production               0.18841
Acrylonitrile, at plant                                   0.00000
Recovered energy, for acrylonitrile                       0.00000
                                        Acrylonitrile, at plant
Acetic acid, at plant                                     0.0000000
Recovered energy, at acetic acid production               0.0000000
Acrylonitrile, at plant                                   1.0000000
Recovered energy, for acrylonitrile                       0.0051834
```